# Where can I download the Litecoin binary for OSX?

Tags: litecoin, mac, mining-software, minerd

Where can I find a compiled litecoin minerd binary for Mac OS X?

Perhaps a multi-coin implementation?

Comment: So Litecoin or multi-coin?

Answer (score 2):

Asked it in the forums, and here's the response:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=039d3d0433adcf037196613c03d139e1&topic=47417.msg605132#msg605132

`Edit` - [direct link to github downloads](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/downloads)

Comment: Actually, it's easy to find from litecoin.org

Comment: Is it worth taking the data from there and posting it here for edification?

Comment: @DominicTancredi - added a direct link to github.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/downloads),
as mentioned in litecoin.org

Answer (score 1):

Today you would be using a mining application like *minerd*:
https://github.com/downloads/metonymous/cpuminer/minerd

Comment: In case you didn't notice, you are replying to an answer that is almost exactly two years old. Back then the standard wallet also had mining capabilities. Link only answers are generally frowned upon, could you please elaborate on what your link leads to?